# regex value check not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Here is [the page](http://order.everyoneon.org/)

If you select one of the 3 modems, it will open up the form below.

On the Billing > Address Line 1 field (left col), I'm trying to check for a PO Box entry and display a hidden message above the field.  We're trying to discourage PO Box, but it should still allow submit, so I'm handling this separately from the jq val plugin on the form.

It's just not working, no matter what I try.  The bind on the input is working, since it's logging properly, must be an issue with the regex, but I can't pinpoint it.

Here is the current js

```
var pobox = new RegExp('[PO.]*\\s?B(ox)?.*\\d+', 'i');

$("#bill_address1").bind("change paste keyup", function(){
        if ($(this).val().match(pobox)) {                               
            $('#pobox-warning').fadeIn(50);
            console.log('box');    
        }       
        else {
            $('#pobox-warning').fadeOut(50);
            console.log('no box'); 
        }

    });
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: It's working for me :) Your expression probably just needs to be tweaked to catch more scenarios.

Comment: That's some *odd* P.O. box validation: "...B993293223". How about you describe what it is you want to accept or reject as valid so we can help.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but `.test()` makes more sense than `.match()` in the context of your regex usage.

Comment: Among other things, you're escaping the backslashes in your character classes.  "\\s" matches a literal "\s", not whitespace.

Comment: @MichaelL. not in this case - he's using the RegExp constructor, so it's necessary to double the backslashes.

Comment: ah, true.  I missed that.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Here's what I'm trying to weed out

   ` P.O.
    PO
    Box
    Post Office`

case insensitive

Any regex recommendaitons based on that?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that a simple regex pattern like

```
/PO *Box/gi
```

would work best. Ignore case. Match the letters PO and any number of spaces followed by the word Box.

Edit:

Or to match the entire PO Box line with or without periods:

```
/P\.?O\.? *Box *\d*/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial part of your regular expression matches *either* a single "P", an "O", or a ".". You probably want something more like:

```
var pobox = /(P\.?O\.?)?\s*B(ox)?.*\d+/i;
```

It's much easier to use the native regular expression syntax in JavaScript when possible, as it appears to be in this case.

Comment: That will match "PO Box 123", "Box 123" or "PO. Box 123" but not "P.O. Box 123".

Comment: @MichaelL. yes that's true; it could use an extra optional "." :)

Answer (score 0):

got it working with
var pattern = /^[P|p]*(OST|ost)*.*\s*[O|o|0]*(ffice|FFICE)*.*\s*[B|b][O|o|0][X|x]\s*(\d.)*/gi;

appreciate everyone's input